# TypeScript refuses Iterator in a for...of

Tags: typescript, iterator, generator

The following code works in my browser without the typings, but TypeScript emits an error saying that `gen()` doesn't have a `[Symbol.iterator]` method which is what is expected for an `Iterable`. This limitation seems strange to me as <del>AFAIK an `Iterator` is a valid object to pass to `for...of`</del>.

```js
function *gen(): Iterator<number> {
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
}

for (const val of gen()) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

Could you explain me what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: Removing the return type from the previous code thus letting TypeScript guess what it is gave me `IterableIterator`, which is making TypeScript happy. So am I not allowed to use a mere `Iterator` in a `for...of`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to my problem is that I made a wrong statement, thinking that an `Iterator` is a valid object to feed to `for...of`.

The reason the example code without typings works in a browser is that the return value of a generator is both an `Iterator` and an `Iterable`, but only an `Iterable` is accepted for `for...of`, as written in the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

By giving the generator an explicit `Iterator` return type I was narrowing it in a way that made TypeScript think it didn't have the `Iterable` capability.

The following code using only an `Iterator` fails as expected in my browser

```js
const it = {
  next: () => ({value: 1, done: false})
}

for (const val of it) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be targeting a recent ES version, pass the `--downlevelIteration` flag, and have as a minimum the "dom" and "esnext" libs for this to work.

```
function* gen() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}

for (let val of gen()) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

Transpiled demo:

```js
"use strict";
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
var __values = (this && this.__values) || function (o) {
    var m = typeof Symbol === "function" && o[Symbol.iterator], i = 0;
    if (m) return m.call(o);
    return {
        next: function () {
            if (o && i >= o.length) o = void 0;
            return { value: o && o[i++], done: !o };
        }
    };
};
var e_1, _a;
function gen() {
    return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        switch (_a.label) {
            case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, 1];
            case 1:
                _a.sent();
                return [4 /*yield*/, 2];
            case 2:
                _a.sent();
                return [4 /*yield*/, 3];
            case 3:
                _a.sent();
                return [2 /*return*/];
        }
    });
}
try {
    for (var _b = __values(gen()), _c = _b.next(); !_c.done; _c = _b.next()) {
        var val = _c.value;
        console.log(val);
    }
}
catch (e_1_1) { e_1 = { error: e_1_1 }; }
finally {
    try {
        if (_c && !_c.done && (_a = _b["return"])) _a.call(_b);
    }
    finally { if (e_1) throw e_1.error; }
}
```

Comment: I know I can iterate through it manually, but I'd like to use it in a `for...of` construct. TypeScript is described as a superset of JavaScript and the code I provided seems like valid JavaScript to me so I presumed it would work.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I was experimenting in VSCode. It works fine, given the right set up in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: It works but without the return type declaration of the generator. By omitting it TypeScript chooses the right one and it appears it is `IterableIterator` and that's only because this type implements `Iterable` that the `for...of` works. As I mentioned in my answer, I was wrong thinking that an `Iterator` was suitable for a `for...of`.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently need to use `Iterable<T>` instead of `Iterator<T>`. `Iterable` is the interface that contains the `[Symbol.iterator]` method that for-of loops invoke, which should return an `Iterator` whose `next()` method produces the series of values.

```js
function* gen(): Iterable<number> {
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
}
```

TypeScript's current handling of Generators seems incomplete. It has a built-in `Generator` type definition, but it's not generic (the produced values are always `any`). It would also cause an error here because it's only marked as an Iterator, not `Iterable`, but we can see that the actual Generator object your browser produces is also `Iterable` (by returning itself, because it's also an `Iterator`).

```
const g = gen();
g[Symbol.iterator]() == g; // true
```